# Concatenating text to options with a certain data attribute value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select element:

```js
function find() {
  var schoolList = document.getElementByID("schoolList");

  if (schoolList.hasAttributes("[data attribute value]") {
      //modify text in found option
    };


  };

  find();
```

```html
<div id="SelectWrapper" class="menu">
  <form>
    <select id="schoolList"> 
            <option value='student' data-tier="student" data->Student 1</option>
            <option value="teacher" data-tier="faculty" data->Teacher</option>
    </form> 
</div>
```

Using pure Javascript, I want to create an if statement within a function that checks to see if an option has an appropriate data attribute value (for instance, "student" or "faculty") and  then adds to or modifies the existing innerHTML/text.

Comment: Should `schoolList` be `classList`?

Comment: @Barmar It should be, thanks for pointing that out and your solution. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` to find all the options with a particular data value, then loop over them.

```
function find() {
    var options = document.querySelectorAll("#schoolList option[data-tier=student]");
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        options[i].innerHTML += " (something)";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example for you

```
function find() {
  var schoolList = document.getElementById("schoolList");

  if (schoolList.hasAttributes("[data attribute value]")) {
    var opts = schoolList.getElementsByTagName("option");
    for (var i = 0, len = opts.length; i < len; i++) {
       var option = opts[i];
       // modify
      if (option["data-tier"] === "student") {
        option.text = "new text content"
      }
    }
    // add new
    for (var i =0; i < 5; i++) {
      var opt = document.createElement("option");
      opt.value = i;
      opt.innerHTML = "Option " + i;
      schoolList.appendChild(opt);
    }
  };
};

find();
```

Comment: `forEach` can only be used on an array. `getElementsByTagName` returns a `NodeList`, not an array.

Comment: Found a hiccup,  the "===" operator for "(option["data-tier"] === "student")" needs to be "=". Regardless, thank you.